# How could I add a list of People in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, mutablelist, listof

I'm trying to create a list of people with name and characteristic.
How could I do this?

```
class Player(val name: String, val nachname: String, val nr: Int)

// And I'm trying to do this:

fun main() {
    val team2 = mutableListOf<Player>()
    team2.add("Max", "Mustermann", 12)
 
    println("${team2.size}")
}
```

Comment: did it even compile ?

Comment: yes  it works ^^

Comment: [tag:java] tag removed as the question has nothing to do with this language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for

```
team2.add(Player("Max", "Mustermann",12))
```